# conditionally create a new column in data frame in R (equivalent of if then statement in SAS)

Tags: r, if-statement, sas, conditional-statements

I've a dataframe where I want to add a new column(newcol) based on the conditionally applying on the others columns(parameter,value). The code has to be written in a way that "if value is not missing then if parameter= "SYSBP" and value >140 and if parameter= "DIABP" and value <80 then newcol="Y". There is no  value for else condition, it has to remain blank.

A glimpse of dataset

```
PATIENT parameter value
001     SYSBP     190
001     DIABP     78
001     SYSBP     180
001     DIABP     72
002     SYSBP     NA
002     DIABP     NA
002     SYSBP     180
002     DIABP     72
```

As a SAS programmer, I'm looking for an equivalent to if then statement and I found ifelse() to be the closest one in R, if someone knows a better match for the if then match, then kindly help me know.

Comment: Some problems with your logic. (1) You say *if parameter="SYSBP" ... and if parameter="DIABP"*, this will never happen, `parameter` will only hold one value. I think you mean to have grouped logic with an OR instead of an AND. (2) *"there is no value for else condition"* won't work. Either you explicitly make the else `NA` (an equivalent of a database "null") or something else. Not "nothing".

Comment: case_when() is closer to IF/THEN/SELECT logic from SAS intellectually but it's slower than most other options.

Answer (score 0):

### Base R

```r
transform(dat, ABC = ifelse( (parameter == "SYSBP" & value > 140) | (parameter == "DIABP" & value < 80), "Y", "unk"))
#   PATIENT parameter value  ABC
# 1       1     SYSBP   190    Y
# 2       1     DIABP    78    Y
# 3       1     SYSBP   180    Y
# 4       1     DIABP    72    Y
# 5       2     SYSBP    NA <NA>
# 6       2     DIABP    NA <NA>
# 7       2     SYSBP   180    Y
# 8       2     DIABP    72    Y
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(ABC = if_else( (parameter == "SYSBP" & value > 140) | (parameter == "DIABP" & value < 80), "Y", "unk"))
#   PATIENT parameter value  ABC
# 1       1     SYSBP   190    Y
# 2       1     DIABP    78    Y
# 3       1     SYSBP   180    Y
# 4       1     DIABP    72    Y
# 5       2     SYSBP    NA <NA>
# 6       2     DIABP    NA <NA>
# 7       2     SYSBP   180    Y
# 8       2     DIABP    72    Y
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(PATIENT = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), parameter = c("SYSBP", "DIABP", "SYSBP", "DIABP", "SYSBP", "DIABP", "SYSBP", "DIABP"), value = c(190L, 78L, 180L, 72L, NA, NA, 180L, 72L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```